# Unsupported Engine Error in Azure Static Web App GitHub Action Deployment

Tags: git, azure, azure-static-web-app

I'm trying to deploy using the default setup with Azure Static Web Applications, but I'm getting an error during the Build and Deploy step.

```
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@angular-devkit/architect@0.1701.3',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: {
npm WARN EBADENGINE     node: '^18.13.0 || >=20.9.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE     npm: '^6.11.0 || ^7.5.6 || >=8.0.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE     yarn: '>= 1.13.0'
npm WARN EBADENGINE   },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.20.2', npm: '8.19.4' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@angular-devkit/build-angular@17.1.3',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: {
npm WARN EBADENGINE     node: '^18.13.0 || >=20.9.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE     npm: '^6.11.0 || ^7.5.6 || >=8.0.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE     yarn: '>= 1.13.0'
npm WARN EBADENGINE   },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.20.2', npm: '8.19.4' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@angular-devkit/build-webpack@0.1701.3',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: {
npm WARN EBADENGINE     node: '^18.13.0 || >=20.9.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE     npm: '^6.11.0 || ^7.5.6 || >=8.0.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE     yarn: '>= 1.13.0'
npm WARN EBADENGINE   },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.20.2', npm: '8.19.4' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@angular-devkit/core@17.1.3',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: {
npm WARN EBADENGINE     node: '^18.13.0 || >=20.9.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE     npm: '^6.11.0 || ^7.5.6 || >=8.0.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE     yarn: '>= 1.13.0'
npm WARN EBADENGINE   },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.20.2', npm: '8.19.4' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@angular-devkit/schematics@17.1.3',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: {
npm WARN EBADENGINE     node: '^18.13.0 || >=20.9.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE     npm: '^6.11.0 || ^7.5.6 || >=8.0.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE     yarn: '>= 1.13.0'
npm WARN EBADENGINE   },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.20.2', npm: '8.19.4' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@angular/animations@17.1.3',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^18.13.0 || >=20.9.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.20.2', npm: '8.19.4' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@angular/cli@17.1.3',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: {
npm WARN EBADENGINE     node: '^18.13.0 || >=20.9.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE     npm: '^6.11.0 || ^7.5.6 || >=8.0.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE     yarn: '>= 1.13.0'
npm WARN EBADENGINE   },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.20.2', npm: '8.19.4' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@angular/common@17.1.3',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^18.13.0 || >=20.9.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.20.2', npm: '8.19.4' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@angular/compiler@17.1.3',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^18.13.0 || >=20.9.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.20.2', npm: '8.19.4' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@angular/compiler-cli@17.1.3',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^18.13.0 || >=20.9.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.20.2', npm: '8.19.4' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@angular/core@17.1.3',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^18.13.0 || >=20.9.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.20.2', npm: '8.19.4' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@angular/forms@17.1.3',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^18.13.0 || >=20.9.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.20.2', npm: '8.19.4' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@angular/platform-browser@17.1.3',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^18.13.0 || >=20.9.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.20.2', npm: '8.19.4' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic@17.1.3',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^18.13.0 || >=20.9.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.20.2', npm: '8.19.4' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@angular/platform-server@17.1.3',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^18.13.0 || >=20.9.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.20.2', npm: '8.19.4' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@angular/router@17.1.3',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^18.13.0 || >=20.9.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.20.2', npm: '8.19.4' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@ngtools/webpack@17.1.3',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: {
npm WARN EBADENGINE     node: '^18.13.0 || >=20.9.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE     npm: '^6.11.0 || ^7.5.6 || >=8.0.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE     yarn: '>= 1.13.0'
npm WARN EBADENGINE   },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.20.2', npm: '8.19.4' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@schematics/angular@17.1.3',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: {
npm WARN EBADENGINE     node: '^18.13.0 || >=20.9.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE     npm: '^6.11.0 || ^7.5.6 || >=8.0.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE     yarn: '>= 1.13.0'
npm WARN EBADENGINE   },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.20.2', npm: '8.19.4' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'rollup@4.9.6',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=18.0.0', npm: '>=8.0.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.20.2', npm: '8.19.4' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'source-map-loader@5.0.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>= 18.12.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.20.2', npm: '8.19.4' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'undici@6.2.1',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=18.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.20.2', npm: '8.19.4' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'vite@5.0.12',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^18.0.0 || >=20.0.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.20.2', npm: '8.19.4' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
```

It seems to be indicating that the packages are using an older version of node, but shouldn't the version of node be dictated by my own app, which I've built with Node 18.13?

Here's my package.json and GitHub Action yaml for reference (the full repo can be found [here](https://github.com/rarDevelopment/rardk-web/blob/main/package.json)):

```
{
  "name": "rardk-web",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "start-port": "ng serve --port 52340",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test",
    "dev:ssr": "ng run rardk-web:serve-ssr",
    "serve:ssr": "node dist/rardk-web/server/main.js",
    "build:ssr": "ng build && ng run rardk-web:server",
    "prerender": "ng run rardk-web:prerender"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^17.1.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^17.0.3",
    "@angular/common": "^17.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^17.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^17.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^17.1.0",
    "@angular/material": "^17.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^17.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^17.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^17.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^17.1.0",
    "@angular/ssr": "^17.1.3",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "luxon": "^3.4.4",
    "marked": "^9.0.0",
    "micromark": "^4.0.0",
    "ngx-markdown": "^17.1.1",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.14.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^17.1.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^17.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^17.1.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.17",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.3.0",
    "@types/luxon": "^3.3.7",
    "@types/node": "^18.18.0",
    "browser-sync": "^3.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.5.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "typescript": "~5.2.0"
  },
  "volta": {
    "node": "18.13.0"
  }
}
```

```
name: Azure Static Web Apps CI/CD

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, synchronize, reopened, closed]
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build_and_deploy_job:
    if: github.event_name == 'push' || (github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action != 'closed')
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Build and Deploy Job
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
        with:
          submodules: true
          lfs: false
      - name: Build And Deploy
        id: builddeploy
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN_AMBITIOUS_ROCK_04F7A950F }}
          repo_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }} # Used for Github integrations (i.e. PR comments)
          action: "upload"
          ###### Repository/Build Configurations - These values can be configured to match your app requirements. ######
          # For more information regarding Static Web App workflow configurations, please visit: https://aka.ms/swaworkflowconfig
          app_location: "/" # App source code path
          api_location: "" # Api source code path - optional
          output_location: "dist/rardk-web/browser" # Built app content directory - optional
          app_build_command: "npm run prerender"
          ###### End of Repository/Build Configurations ######

  close_pull_request_job:
    if: github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action == 'closed'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Close Pull Request Job
    steps:
      - name: Close Pull Request
        id: closepullrequest
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN_AMBITIOUS_ROCK_04F7A950F }}
          action: "close"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need additional configuration in the `package.json` file... You can try adding `engines`, then `node` to your `package.json` file and specifying which version of *node* you need. [Something like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7PnwJ.png)